# Traefik and Nginx with HTTPS on Docker / 400 Bad Request

Tags: docker, nginx, https, traefik

I'm trying to build stack with Traefik and Nginx based on Docker. Without HTTPS is everything fine, but I get an error as soon as I put on HTTPS configuration.

I'm getting this error from Nginx on `example.com`: **400 Bad Request / The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port.** In the address bar I can see the green lock saying connection is secure.

Certbot works fine so I have real SSL certificate inside the proper folder.

I can get to the Traefik dasboard when I visit `traefik.example.com` but I have to accept no SSL browser warning and dasboard is also working without HTTPS.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.4'
services:
    traefik:
        image: traefik:latest
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
            - "8080:8080"
        volumes:
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
            - ./traefik/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml
            - ../letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
        labels:
            - traefik.backend=traefik
            - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:traefik.example.com
            - traefik.port=8080
        networks:
           - traefik
    nginx:
        image: nginx:latest
        volumes:
            - ../www:/var/www
            - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
            - ../letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
        labels:
            - traefik.backend=nginx
            - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:example.com
            - traefik.port=80
            - traefik.port=443
        networks:
            - traefik
networks:
    traefik:
        driver: overlay
        external: true
        attachable: true
```

traefik.toml

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

[web]
    address = ":8080"

[entryPoints]
    [entryPoints.http]
        address = ":80"
        [entryPoints.http.redirect]
            entryPoint = "https"
    [entryPoints.https]
        address = ":443"
        [entryPoints.https.tls]
            [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
                certFile = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem"
                keyFile = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem"

[docker]
    domain="example.com"
    watch = true
    exposedByDefault = true
    swarmMode = false
```

nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;

    server_name www.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

    root /var/www/public;
    index index.html;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First there is no need to have SSL redirection configured in both Traefik and Nginx. Also Traefik frontend is matching only `non www` variant but backend app expects `www`. Finally Traefik `web` provider is deprecated so there should be newer `api` provider.

Answer (score 0):

As I just stumbled upon a similar problem with Traefik v2

```
400 Bad Request / The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port
```

with an Nginx error log stating

```
400 client sent plain HTTP request to HTTPS port while reading client request headers
```

and scratching my head over it, I finally found the source of that error. It's not that the TLS certs were invalid or something in the transport broken, but that the wiring between routers, services and port mappings were off.

Previously I did not see, that the Docker Compose stack had an Nginx container only listening on `80/tcp`. I assumed everything's ok as I attached the ports to Traefik load balancers attached to a separate service per http/https endpoints with separated routers. This somehow did not work:

```
- "traefik.http.services.proxy.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
- "traefik.http.services.proxy-secure.loadbalancer.server.port=443"
```

Intermediary I now opened `port: - "8008:80" - "8443:443"` and got it working. Investigating further what's wrong with Traefik ports as those should get `exposed` per default. This is not a solution as those ports are now available to the outside world, but I am leaving this explanation here as I could not find anything on this topic that would point me in the right direction, so hopefully it's helpful for someone else later on.